# ArrayCollection Filter for discr column

Tags: symfony, twig

I have an array Collection from my Entity
I have 2 other entities that inherit from the main entity

```
this is my code:

/**
 * FooBase
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="mytable")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *          "foo"                        = "\Entity\Foo",
 *          "bar"                        = "\Entity\Bar",
 * })
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="FooBaseRepository")
 */
```

In Twig i have this Code

```
{{ profile.fooBaseCollection|length }}
```

I will return the length of the entire ArrayCollection

I can only retrieve items with desc = foo?
Something like

```
$foo instanceof Foo
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to separate objects from Foo and Bar types in your twig template.

In my opinion, it's not somthing that you should do in a view, you can filter your array collection in your action or in a service and send the results to your view.

```
$foos = $profile->fooBaseCollection->filter(
    function($entry) {
        return $entry instanceof Foo;
    }
);

$bars = $profile->fooBaseCollection->filter(
    function($entry) {
        return $entry instanceof Bar;
    }
);

$twigVars = [
    'foos' => $foos,
    'bars' => $bars
];
```

If you really want to make this process in your view, the best way to do this is to write this code in a [twig extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html).